# ListView doesn't appear (doesn't show any item)

Tags: android, listview

I don't know why, but the ListView is not showing any item. It should get all records from database and display on screen. But it doesn't work. I got no errors in LogCat.

This is my code:

```
public class Teste extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile1";
private ListView mListView;

ArrayList<WordDefinition> allWordDefinitions=new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();


DictionaryDatabase DictionaryDatabase;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    DictionaryDatabase=new DictionaryDatabase(this); 
    allWordDefinitions=DictionaryDatabase.getAllWords(); 


                mListView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View View, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = View;
            if (v==null) {
                v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }
            TextView textView=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listItemTextView);
            textView.setText(allWordDefinitions.get(position).word);

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return allWordDefinitions.size();
        }
    });

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            Intent intent =new Intent(Teste.this, WordDefinitionDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("word", allWordDefinitions.get(position).word);
            intent.putExtra("definition", allWordDefinitions.get(position).definition);


            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

 }
```

DictionaryDatabase

```
public class DictionaryDatabase {
private static final String TAG = "DictionaryDatabase";

public static final String KEY_WORD = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
public static final String KEY_DEFINITION = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionary";
private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTSdictionary";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private final DictionaryOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;
private static final HashMap<String,String> mColumnMap = buildColumnMap();

public DictionaryDatabase(Context context) {
    mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DictionaryOpenHelper(context);
}

private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMap() {
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put(KEY_WORD, KEY_WORD);
    map.put(KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_DEFINITION);
    map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
            BaseColumns._ID);
    map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
    map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
    return map;
}




public Cursor getWord(String rowId, String[] columns) {
    String selection = "rowid = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

}

public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

}

private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {

    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
    builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, KEY_WORD + " ASC");

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return cursor;
}

private static class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context mHelperContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                " USING fts3 (" +
                KEY_WORD + ", " +
                KEY_DEFINITION + ");";



    DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mHelperContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mDatabase = db;
        mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
        loadDictionary();
    }



    private void loadDictionary() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadWords();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void loadWords() throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");
        final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "//");
                if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
                if (id < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
    }


    public long addWord(String word, String definition) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_WORD, word);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, definition);

        return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public long insertData(WordDefinition wordDefinition) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=mDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_WORD, wordDefinition.word);
    values.put(KEY_DEFINITION, wordDefinition.definition);

    return database.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, values);        

}

public long updateData(WordDefinition wordDefinition) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=mDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_WORD, wordDefinition.word);
    values.put(KEY_DEFINITION, wordDefinition.definition);

    return database.update(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, values, KEY_WORD+" =?", new String[]{wordDefinition.word});   

}

public void deleteData(WordDefinition wordDefinition) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=mDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String queryString="DELETE FROM "+FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE+" WHERE "+KEY_WORD+" = '"+wordDefinition.word+"'";

    database.execSQL(queryString);
  }




public ArrayList<WordDefinition> getAllWords() {
ArrayList<WordDefinition> arrayList=new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();
SQLiteDatabase database=mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();

String selectAllQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE;
Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectAllQueryString, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {            
        WordDefinition wordDefinition=new WordDefinition(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORD)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEFINITION)));
        arrayList.add(wordDefinition);              
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());          
}   
return arrayList;
}

public WordDefinition getWordDefinition(String word) {
SQLiteDatabase database=mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
WordDefinition wordDefinition=null;

String selectQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE+ " WHERE "+KEY_WORD+" = '"+word+ "'";
Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectQueryString, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    wordDefinition=new WordDefinition(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORD)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEFINITION)));

}   

return wordDefinition;

}

public WordDefinition getWordDefinition(long id) {
SQLiteDatabase database=mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
WordDefinition wordDefinition=null;

String selectQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE+ " WHERE "+BaseColumns._ID+" = '"+id+ "'";
Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectQueryString, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    wordDefinition=new WordDefinition(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORD)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEFINITION)));

}   

return wordDefinition;

}


 public void initializeDatabaseFortheFirstTime(ArrayList<WordDefinition> wordDefinitions) {
SQLiteDatabase database=mDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
database.execSQL("BEGIN");

ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

for (WordDefinition wordDefinition : wordDefinitions) {
    contentValues.put(KEY_WORD, wordDefinition.word);
    contentValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, wordDefinition.definition);           
    database.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, contentValues);
}
database.execSQL("COMMIT");

}



 }
```

WordDefinition

```
public class WordDefinition {
String word,definition;

public WordDefinition(String word,ArrayList<String> alldefinition) {
    this.word=word;

    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    for (String string : alldefinition) {
        stringBuilder.append(string);
    }       
    this.word=stringBuilder.toString();

}

public WordDefinition(String word,String alldefinition) {
    this.word=word;     
    this.definition=alldefinition;

}

}
```

Comment: Did you check if your arraylist really contains objects? Maybe your arraylist is null.

Comment: @EpicNinja It's funny, because this doesn't work at first run, but if I change the orientation of smartphone or finish application and reopen it the ListView runs ok. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

change your code as..

```
Log.e("List size",""+allWordDefinitions.size());

                mListView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View View, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = View;

LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
            YourActivity.this.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

if (v==null) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }
            TextView textView=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listItemTextView);
            textView.setText(allWordDefinitions.get(position).word);

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return allWordDefinitions.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return allWordDefinitions.size();
        }
    });
```

and check your log cat.. what is the size of list.
this line `Log.e("List size",""+allWordDefinitions.size());` will print the size.

Comment: and try to change `getlayoutInflator()` to `LayoutInflater.from(this.context)`

Comment: also check your size of list/array in adapter.

Comment: I got confused. Could you edit your answer above showing me how to follow your steps: "myList..." "LayoutInflater" adjusted in my code? Sorry, I'm a newbie!! Thanks

Comment: It continues doesn't work. According to Log Cat the List Size is 0. When I change the orientation or close app e reopen it, the List is filled.

Comment: It means the ListView gets all the record as it should be! Inflates, etc...but NOT at first run :/! See the edits above, I put my Dictionary Database Class

Comment: it seems your `loadDictionary();` creating problem. use Async task for this.
i think control passes after starting the thread and not load the resources till that time.

Comment: @sorabh bans I don't know how use Async taks. I should use it in my Activity or DictionaryDatabse? Sorry... I'm a newbie. Could you give any suggestion (maybe a tutorial that explains this)?

Comment: Nobody else understood my problem? I need some help!!